# select all columns but make certain columns equal to a scalar in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Something like:

```
SELECT *, COLUMN1 = 3, COLUMN2 = 1 FROM TABLE1
```

However, I would like the order of the columns to be the same as when select only `SELECT *`
and not add any extra columns like `column1` and `column2` but replace the existing ones that are included in `*`. `TABLE1` contains the columns `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2`.

Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you need to explicitly list the columns that you want from `TABLE1`, in the order that you want them in. There's no magic way to get this done

Answer (score 0):

The order of the columns is the order listed in the table, as determined by ORDINAL_POSITION in the table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

This is the same order that they are presented in SQL Server Management Studio.  So, here is a trick.  Go into a query window and type "select ".  Then, go to the Object Explorer part of SQL Server Management Studio and open the databse, then the table, until you see the "Columns" header with a folder next to it.

Now, drag the folder right after the "select ".

Voila!  The columns appear, separated by commas.

Fill in the rest of what you need for the query.  Make constant what you want constant.  And you are done.

Otherwise, you would have to use dynamic SQL to accomplish this.